# Use VBA in Excel without exact rows in code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code in Excel VBA

```
If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Value, "ž") Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("8").RowHeight = 0
        Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("8").RowHeight = 27
End If
```

But if I insert a new row in Excel row number C7 and 8 is no longer 7 and 8. How can I write my code better to allow move things in my Excel and insert new rows without I have to edit my code.

I think something simular to write a formula in Excel. If you move the formula and the numbers everything works anyway.

Comment: You have several options. (1) If there is some unique value in the row you want to use in your code, you could search for it, which would provide the row number to use in your code; (2) If it's always the 'first or last' row, you can find that also.

Comment: Use named ranges, eg `ActiveSheet.Range("MyRange").Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with variables.

```
Dim row, column As Integer
column = 7
For row = 1 to ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value, "ž") Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(row - 1).RowHeight = 0
                Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My").Visible = True
            ActiveSheet.Rows(row - 1).RowHeight = 27
        End If
Next row
```

You could iterate over rows to check your condition. You could easily iterate over the columns to with another loop within.